# How to Properly Enable beforeToday DateBox Option from dev.jtsage

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, jquery-mobile, datepicker

I'm using a [DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/) with the "datebox" data-role, and Web Forms:

```
<input name="date" id="date" type="date" value="" data-role="datebox" 
  data-options='{
    "beforeToday": true, 
    "dateFormat": "mm/dd/YYYY", 
    "mode": "datebox", 
    "lockInput": false, 
    "centerHoriz": true, 
    "centerVert": true, 
    "showInitialValue": true}' />
```

Everything works fine, including `dateFormat`, except the part where I try to limit the dates to current and past dates. I'm able to select a future date and the future date displays in the input field. The [documentation](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/opt/limit.html) states that I should be able to limit dates in many ways but I have not been able to get them to be limited in any way. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try setting `min` and `max`.

Comment: Adding "min" and "max" values does nothing as far as I can tell. '<input name="scoreDate" id="scoreDate" type="date" value="" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"maxDays": 1, "beforeToday": true, "dateFormat": "mm/dd/YYYY", "mode": "datebox", "centerHoriz": true, "centerVert": true, "showInitialValue": true}' runat="server"  />'

Comment: Looks like it works in calbox and flipbox modes, but not datebox.  Have you contacted the developer?

Comment: @ezanker I just tried to contact the developer after reading your suggestive comment.

Comment: is that solved or not!!!

Comment: @Aravin This is still a problem.

Comment: @haleonj check this one yaar http://jsfiddle.net/ktbcP/444/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, feature was broken - is fixed now. (sorry about that, been away from it for some time)

Your implementation is completely correct.

Comment: Thank you for letting everyone know. Is there a version we should download (stable vs current)?